# jquery parse ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jquery's ajax method, and I need help parsing data coming back from backend server.

server response will be either "valid" or "not valid.

Currently my "if statement logic is not working, this is what I have tried so far).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/phone-valid.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {userid: $.trim($('#userid').val())},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        if (result.indexOf("not valid")) {
            ("#mustbevalid").val("You must validate your phone number");
            console.log("Phone hasn't been validated");
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    }
});
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `if(data=="valid")` would seem more logical than `if(result.indexOf("not valid"))` ... `result` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking `result.indexOf`, but your response data is in `data` not `result`. Additionally, indexOf returns the position, which could be 0. So change to:

```
if(data.indexOf("not valid") > -1) {
```

---

Side note: this method of checking a result is error-prone and usually undesirable. It would be better for you to output a JSON object with a success property.

Example success response:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
// Outputs: {"success":true}
```

Example error response:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
// Outputs: {"success":false}
```

Now, you can parse the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType : 'json', // <-- tell jQuery we're expecting JSON
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // success
        } else {
            // error
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf will return the position in the string.  So use this instead:

```
if(data.indexOf("not valid") == 0)
```